# Differences when doing Python indexing during numpy variable assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working on transcribing some code from MATLAB to Python. While there are a lot of difference between Python and MATLAB (like zero indexing vs 1 indexing in matrices), there are also some similarities. However, I am still struggling to know when to use the following notation in python:

Suppose A is a 2D numpy array, when should I use one notation over the other?

```
A[1,3] = 0
```

vs

```
A[1][3] = 0
```

The same applies to when I assign multiple values to a new variable, for example:

```
M = A[1,3]
```

vs

```
M = A[1][3]
```

They don't seem to be the same. I just noticed that I bumped into a bug after thinking that both of these commands output the same result, when they in fact do not:

Version 1 (where regions2 is a 4D numpy array):

```
regions2 = regions2[:][3:][:][:]
```

where regions2 goes from dimensions: (**25**,8,477,477) to dimensions: (**22**,8,477,477), VS:

Version 2(where regions2 is the same initial 4D numpy array):

```
regions2 = regions2[:,3:,:,:]
```

where regions2 goes from dimensions: (25,**8**,477,477) to (25,**5**,477,477), which makes more sense to me than Version1.

Comment: Essentially always do it the way with the commas.

Comment: I think the new problem that I have is that I have other variable assignments where I have a 2D list (where each element in the list has variable length) and I can't use comma's for that, since it spits an error out. So I have to use the brackets instead, but it flips the order. Not what is the best way to proceed, that makes my code less confusing.

Comment: "So I have to use the brackets instead, but it flips the order" - that sounds like you have some other bug, or you're trying to apply multidimensional slicing to a list (which doesn't support that).

Comment: With varisble length sublists you don't get a 2d array.  Think of cells in matlab.  When in doubt check the `shape` and `dtype`.

Comment: @user2357112 it looks like I am trying to apply mutlidimensional slicing. I guess what you're saying is that python 2.7 does not support that? My best best would be to create a new mutlidimensional list with the new dimensions and copy the component from the selected indexes to my new variable? Would that make sense?